# Javascript Infinite For Loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, infinite-loop

I am learning for loops in javascript and trying some things I wrote the following basic code.

This code generates an infinite loop that only prints the number 4 indefinitely in the console.

The problem is that i don't understand the logic behind this and the exact reason why it happens

```
for(let i = 0; i = 4; i++){
   console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: or `i  =< 4` to print every number up to 4

Comment: The second expression has to be a boolean condition, but yours is an assignment (which is truthy). So it loops forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop, the condition part uses an [assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) `=`, you should use a [comparison operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) such as `!==`. Note also that the condition should be false in order to exit the for loop. So `!==` it is (or `<=`, which I dislike for personal reasons), instead of `===`.

```js
for(let i = 0; i !== 4; i++){
   console.log(i);
}
```

So your code runs indefinitely because `i = 4` is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy). And it prints 4 because `i = 4` assigns 4 to i **after** increment

Answer (score 1):

`i = 4` is an expression which would return `4` and `4` is trucy value so the condition never gets false and the loop never ends

```js
console.log(i=4); //4
console.log(Boolean(i=4)); //true
```

You should use less than operator

```js
for(let i = 0; i <= 4; i++){
   console.log(i);
}
```